# Swift Mailer code isn't working

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send my first PHP email using SwiftMailer, but it isn't working. 
The code is below

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    &nbsp;<p></p>
    <?php
    require_once  'swift_required.php';
    ?>

    <?php

    // Create the Transport
     $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.office365.com', 587,    'ssl')
       ->setUsername('scanner@here.com')
       ->setPassword('scanner');
     $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    // Create a message
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
    ->setFrom(array('user@here.com' => 'test user'))
    ->setTo(array('support@here.com'=> 'IT Support'))
    ->setBody('Here is the message itself');
    $numSent = $mailer->send($message);
    printf("Sent %d messages\n", $numSent);
     if (!$mailer->send($message, $failures)) {
      echo "Failures:";
      print_r($failures);
    } else {
        echo 'email sent successfully';
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I get absolutely no errors or anything.  If I put php code or HTML tags before my call to $mailer, I get a response.  But if I do it after the call, ...nothing.  It's as if there's a stop someplace in the code.

Comment: at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: `$failures` is not set,

Comment: also, from the Swift docs... `

For SSL or TLS encryption to work your PHP installation must have appropriate OpenSSL transports wrappers. You can check if "tls" and/or "ssl" are present in your PHP installation by using the PHP function stream_get_transports()`